# protobuf-python, sometimes access instance but get type info

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I use a nested protobuf struct in python.
Sometimes weird problem happen, to i use pdb to stop at the scene, and serialize the data to a file, then parse from another shell. the result is the data is correct.

Let's see:

stop in pb, print some values:

```
(Pdb) p maya_pack.SerializeToString()
'.... pb value ... for privacy not put text here .... '
(Pdb) open('t.bin','wb').write(maya_pack.SerializeToString())    <==== save to t.bin
(Pdb) print maya_pack
pack_type: CLIENT
client {
  cmd: MAYA_CMD_SEND_MESSAGE
  send_message {
    CLIENT_INFO {
      ....
    }
    ....
  }
}

(Pdb) print maya_pack.client
cmd: MAYA_CMD_SEND_MESSAGE
send_message {
  CLIENT_INFO {
    ....
    SESSION: "dba8b5c24421bc822731196657932b2d"
  }
  ......
}

(Pdb) print maya_pack.client.send_message
CLIENT_INFO {
  ....
  SESSION: "dba8b5c24421bc822731196657932b2d"
}

(Pdb) print maya_pack.client.send_message.CLIENT_INFO
<class 'maya_client_pb2.T_CLIENT_INFO'>          <======= this should print the value of CLIENT_INFO not the type info.
(Pdb) print maya_client_pb2.T_CLIENT_INFO
<class 'maya_client_pb2.T_CLIENT_INFO'>    <===== T_CLIENT_INFO is the message class.
```

Then, in another shell, open t.bin and see the result:

```
p = maya_pack_pb2.MAYA_PACK()
>>> p.ParseFromString(open('t.bin','r').read())
>>> p
<maya_pack_pb2.MAYA_PACK object at 0x10b0a1520>
>>> print p
pack_type: CLIENT
client {
  cmd: MAYA_CMD_SEND_MESSAGE
  send_message {
    CLIENT_INFO {
      ....
            SESSION: "dba8b5c24421bc822731196657932b2d"
    }
  }
}
>>> print p.client.send_message
CLIENT_INFO {
  ....
  SESSION: "dba8b5c24421bc822731196657932b2d"
}
>>> print p.client.send_message.CLIENT_INFO          <====== great. correct result.
...
SESSION: "dba8b5c24421bc822731196657932b2d"

>>> print type(p.client.send_message.CLIENT_INFO)      
<class 'maya_client_pb2.T_CLIENT_INFO'>        <====== great. correct result.
```

Comment: It might help if you posted the relevant parts of your `.proto` file. Is there both a type and a field named `CLIENT_INFO`?

Comment: Thank you @Thomas.  The problem is solved. The root cause is that I use the incorrect way to construct a send_message instance -  maya_client_pb2.SEND_MESSAGE. the correct way is maya_client_pb2.SEND_MESSAGE(). I didn't notice the problem because it mostly worked.